# Flip Images on Radio Button Change

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, toggle, image-rotation

I have a radio list where the buttons have been replaced by two image. when unchecked, imgFront is visible, when checked, imgBack is visible. The aim is to flip the image using CSS transform to reveal the other imagine on check. How would this be done?

HTML:

```
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="1" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label1" for="cmn-toggle-1">
         <img id="imgFront1" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Refuse.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img id="imgBack1" src="~/Content/img/Categories/RefuseLabel.png" width="65" height="65" class="hidden"/>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="2" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label2" for="cmn-toggle-2">
         <img id="imgFront2" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Water.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img id="imgBack2" src="~/Content/img/Categories/WaterLabel.png" width="65" height="65" class="hidden"/>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-3" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="3" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label3" for="cmn-toggle-3">
         <img id="imgFront3" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Building.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img id="imgBack3" src="~/Content/img/Categories/BuildingLabel.png" width="65" height="65" class="hidden"/>
   </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 3 - YES NO
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label::before, input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label::before {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label::after {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=category]:radio').change(function() {
            if(this.checked==true){
               //do something
            }
            else{
                //doo something else
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to switch the image on the selected radio button you can vastly simplify your CSS.

In your HTML, change all the `id` attributes on your `label > img` tags to `class="imgFront"` and `class="imgBack"` like so:

```
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="1" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label1" for="cmn-toggle-1">
         <img class="imgFront" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Refuse.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img class="imgBack" src="~/Content/img/Categories/RefuseLabel.png" width="65" height="65"/>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="2" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label2" for="cmn-toggle-2">
         <img class="imgFront" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Water.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img class="imgBack" src="~/Content/img/Categories/WaterLabel.png" width="65" height="65"/>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-3" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" value="3" type="radio" name="category" />
    <label id="Label3" for="cmn-toggle-3">
         <img class="imgFront" src="~/Content/img/Categories/Building.png" width="65" height="65"/>
         <img class="imgBack" src="~/Content/img/Categories/BuildingLabel.png" width="65" height="65"/>
   </label>
</div>
```

You can also drop the `class="hidden"` on the "back" images. Unless that class is defined and needed in a different CSS, it's not really being used here.

In your CSS, leave the COMMON section and drop everything else. Three simple CSS rules will then handle the image flipping. Your CSS should then look like:

```
/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  RADIO BUTTON IMAGE FLIPPING WHEN SELECTED
============================================================ */         
.switch > label > .imgBack {
    display: none;
}

.switch > input[type='radio']:checked + label > .imgFront {
    display: none;
}

.switch > input[type='radio']:checked + label > .imgBack {
    display: block;
}
```

Your JavaScript is fine, although it's not necessary here for the image flipping. If you need to take care of other activities when one of the radio buttons is selected then keep it, otherwise you can get rid of it.

That should do it. If you want to add more fancy transitions with CSS you can certainly do that. This solution will simply perform the image swap for you using purely CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm studying and I am going to take your solution as concrete. I have a deadline on Monday. So really thanks.